# request forwarding with ServletHttpHandlerAdapter spring web-flux in servlet 3.1 container

Tags: spring-webflux, servlet-3.0, spring-web, servlet-3.1

As per [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-httphandler)  on servlet 3.1 container ServletHttpHandlerAdapter can be registered as a servlet and can support nio.
I need to forward request to some other resource as below

```
asyncContext.getRequest().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/OtherResource")
                .forward(asyncContext.getRequest(), asyncContext.getResponse());
```

on calling forward i'm getting below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:211)
at com.nucleus.OtherServlet.doGet(OtherServlet.java:30)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
at com.nucleus.AsyncRequestProcessor.run(AsyncRequestProcessor.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Which is correct as spring creates org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse and calls response.getOutputStream() initially, now how to support request forwarding?

Issue also logged to spring jira for discussion - [Link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17637)

Answer (score 0):

Spring WebFlux can be deployed on a Servlet 3.1 container thanks to the `ServletHttpHandlerAdapter` - but it doesn't mean you are allowed to use Servlet specific APIs in that application.

First, once you're using the async I/O Servlet features you're not allowed to mix them with blocking I/O calls on the Servlet API ([see this presentation about Servlet 3.1 async IO](https://youtu.be/uGXsnB2S_vc)).

So in general, you should never try and fetch Servlet-specific objects from the `ServerWebExchange`, but rather code against this new HTTP foundation in Spring WebFlux.

[There is an issue about supporting forwarding at the WebFlux level](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14537), but I'm not sure this would ultimately solve your problem. I don't understand the specifics of the issue you're hitting, but Spring WebFlux already supports templating engines that use blocking I/O ([see Freemarker support here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/result/view/freemarker)).

If the templating engine you're trying to support is tied to Servlet, then you won't be able to get proper WebFlux support as you can run Spring WebFlux applications on non-servlet environments.